# Reading negative values from excel file using php

Tags: php, excel

I need to read excel data. so i've used [phpExcelReader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/) . It worked great, but unfortunately it doesn't reading negative values in 64 bit architecture.

In 32 bit architecture it doesn't any problems in reading negative values. I don't know how to get around this issue?  Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The webserver has 64 bit processor and php version 5.3.4 and it runs on linux platform

Comment: What do you mean by "reading negative values" exactly? What happens, what errors or broken output do you get? Can you show some example data and code? What exactly is 64-bit about your system - the OS, the web server, the PHP version?

Comment: @Pekka It is 64 bit processor and the program prints a value like '1073736824' while reading a cell value that has -5000 .

Comment: I'm not sure whether the processor architecture is at fault here. What PHP version are you running on what platform? Maybe add that information to your question

Comment: @Pekka the same file works good in my local system so i checked the cpu info and it says x86_64, i checked the server for the same. and both are same. but only php version is differs. In webserver they have 5.3.4 and in my system i've php version 5.2.5. Is this cause the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below link on this issue. May be this is what you are looking for,
http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/issues/detail?id=123 also http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/issues/detail?id=28

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify this issue once again. Find the OLERead class (in my case in excel_reader2.php) and replace the bodies of both these two methods:

_GetInt4d() and GetInt4d()

with this code:

```
function GetInt4d($data, $pos) {
    $value = ord($data[$pos]) | (ord($data[$pos+1]) << 8) | (ord($data[$pos+2]) << 16) | (ord($data[$pos+3]) << 24);
    if ($value>=4294967294) {
        $value=-2;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Now the class supports both the 32 and 64 bit OS architectures. I hope it is now clear and helps.